# Unexpected values in two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, typescript, shallow-copy

This is probably a duplicate question but I didn't know how to search for it.

Can someone explain the bevior from the code snippet to me?

I am trying to iterate over a 2-dimensional array, setting each value to the index of the containing row. Yet all values are somehow set to the last row's index.

```
const string1 = "abc";
const string2 = "abcd";

const matrix = new Array(string1.length).fill(new Array(string2.length).fill(0));

for (let i = 0; i < string1.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < string2.length; j++) {
    console.log(i);
    matrix[i][j] = i;
  }
}

console.log(matrix);
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
[ [ 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2 ] ]
```

Expected output:

```
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2 ] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation:

> [`fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) changes all values of an array to a static `value`. [...] Note all elements in the array will be this exact value: if `value` is an object, each slot in the array will reference that object.

That means in each of your rows you will reference the same object (= [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), remember: arrays are objects in JavaScript) meaning you always change the same array resulting in the last change being the one you can observe by printing it.

```js
const string1 = "abc";
const string2 = "abcd";

const matrix = new Array(string1.length).fill(new Array(string2.length).fill(0));

for (let i = 0; i < string1.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < string2.length; j++) {
    matrix[i][j] = i;
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix));
// Prove that they are actually the same reference => same object
console.log(matrix[0] === matrix[1]) // true
```

You could use the following approach to initialize the array.

```js
const string1 = "abc";
const string2 = "abcd";

const matrix = [...new Array(string1.length)].map((_, i) => new Array(string2.length).fill(i));

console.log(JSON.stringify(matrix));

// now we have different references => different objects
console.log(matrix[0] === matrix[1]) // returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in the posted code, the call to

```
.fill(new Array(string2.length)
```

creates a single array when evaluating `fill` 's argument, which in turn means `fill` will set all elements of the array it is called on to the selfsame Array object.

This way this snippet creates second dimensional arrays only involves creating a single array for `matrix`'s first dimensional array:

```js
const string1 = "abc";
const string2 = "abcd";
const matrix = new Array(string1.length).fill(0);
matrix.forEach( (_, i, rows) => rows[i] = new Array(string2.length).fill(i));
console.log( matrix)

console.log("\nSee note about spread for this: ", [...new Array(string1.length)]);
```

Notes

- Array prototype methods such as `forEach` and `map` do not process empty slots in arrays they are called on (i.e. they skip over array entries that have not been assigned a value).
- The `fill(0)` call at the end of the `matrix` declaration in the snippet ensures none of its slots are empty. (It could have used `fill()` with no argument to fill empty slots with `undefined`).
- Of interest, but not used in the snippet, using spread syntax to initialize one array from another converts *empty slots in the spread array* to elements with the value `undefined` in the initialized array

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following workaround will helpful to get the final result.

```js
const string1 = "abc";
const string2 = "abcd";

const matrix = [];

for (let i = 0; i < string1.length; i++) {
    const arrayJ = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < string2.length; j++) {
        arrayJ.push(i);
    }
    matrix.push(arrayJ);
}

console.log(matrix);
```